# How to save a file in place even with backups?

Tags: files, backup

In order to prevent NFS caching from leading to stale files, I need to preserve the inode of a file when Emacs saves it.  Normally, it does so anyway, but apparently not if backup files come into play.

One can test this easily by adding the following snippet to .emacs, forcing Emacs to create backups with every save:

```
(defun force-backup-of-buffer ()
  (setq buffer-backed-up nil))
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'force-backup-of-buffer)
```

Can one make Emacs save files *always* in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to set `backup-by-copying` for that.